# Mex : How to properly assign a sparse matrix to LHS (output) and how to properly clean memory

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have written a mex code which sends a scalar and a matrix to C-code from matlab code. My code is supposed to `return the sparse matrix after putting it in` [TAUCS format](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/tsnnls/tags/start/taucs.pdf) (page 12; also a column major format).

I am concerned that I may `not be assigning LHS correctly` and returning null pointer or I may `not be cleaning the memory properly`. Would someone please let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Part of my matlab code:

```
% Create system matrix (size 8448 x 3264) 
smA_System = ConstructSystemMatrix();

x = 9;
y = ones(3);

% This works fine
z = mexcallingmatlab(x, y);

% This gives error
z = mexcallingmatlab(x, smA_System);
```

My mex code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"   // definition of Matlab sparse matrix

#include<stdio.h>

//#include "/usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/taucs.h"
#include "/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/taucs_basic/taucs.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *y, *z, x;

    /* Declare variable */
    mwSize mrows,ncols;
    int status;
    mwSize nzmax;
    mwIndex *irs,*jcs,j,k;

    /*  Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if (nrhs != 2) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("Two inputs required.");
    if (nlhs != 1) 
        mexErrMsgTxt("One output required.");

    /* Check to make sure the first input argument is a scalar. */
    if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) ||     mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxGetN(prhs[0])*mxGetM(prhs[0]) != 1) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input x must be a scalar.");
    }

    /* Get the scalar input x. */
    x = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

    /* Create a pointer to the input matrix y. */
    y = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);


     /* Check data type dimensions of the matrix input y. */
    if (!(mxIsDouble(prhs[1]))){
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:DKU", "Input argument must be of type double.");
    }

    if (mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[1]) != 2){
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:DKU", "Input argument must be two dimensional\n");
    }

     /* Get the size and pointers to input data */
    mrows =mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    ncols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

    // Verify the matrix y is infact sparse
    if (!(mxIsSparse(prhs[1]))){
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB: DKU", "Input matrix is not sparse\n");
    }else{
        //Work with irs and jcs directly instead of row-column pairs that are less compact.     
        sr  = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
        jcs = mxGetJc(prhs[1]);     
        irs = mxGetIr(prhs[1]);
    }

   // Now converting sparse matrix to TAUCS format
    taucs_ccs_matrix *A;
    A = (taucs_ccs_matrix*)malloc(sizeof(taucs_ccs_matrix));
    A->n = ncols;
    A->m = mrows;   
    A->flags = TAUCS_DOUBLE;

    // Allocating spaces
    int nnz = jcs[ncols]; 
    A->colptr       = (int*)mxMalloc(sizeof(int)*(A->n+1));
    A->rowind   = (int*)mxMalloc(sizeof(int)*nnz);
    A->values.d     = (double*)mxMalloc(sizeof(taucs_double)*nnz);  

    int icolOffset = 0;  // Matlab "SPARSE" indices start with 0 vs 0 based in C    

    A->colptr = jcs-icolOffset;
    A->rowind = irs-icolOffset;
    A->values.d = sr;

    /* Create a C pointer to a copy of the output matrix. */
     memcpy(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), &A, sizeof(A)); 

    //Freeing spaces
    mxFree(A->colptr);
    mxFree(A->rowind);
    mxFree(A->values.d);        
}
```

Also, can someone confirm that what's basically written as "[colptr](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html)" is `not a real pointer`; but is just like a pointer `conceptually` ?

Comment: I suggest passing individual fields of A to matlab as simple arrays and assemble them to whatever you want in matlab. And if you want to fill data into lhs, use memcpy(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), sourcePtr, size); and make sure the array is the correct type and big enough to hold the data.

Comment: I have been told that passing pointer to matrix is more efficient.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the expression "A = mxGetPr(plhs[0])". This effectively overwrites you old pointer from malloc (and don't you miss a free as well?). So, you call mxFree on a pointer allocated to by a different allocation.

Comment: @Henrik I think that you are right. Since my C++ or mex is not that good; so, I may be making mistake. I corrected it now.

Comment: Instead of malloc first then copy, you can do it the other way. I'll use mxCreateDoubleMatrix() to allocate memory, then use mxGetPr(plhs[0]) to get the pointer, then pass that pointer to your working C code to fill the result directly into matlab work space. I usually does this using a 3-layer approach. Bottom: in C, plain C function, Middle: in C with Mex API to convert plain matlab array/struct from/to plain C struct/array; top: in Matlab, input/output datatype check and conversion, complex data structure conversion(from plain matlab array to complex matlab structure, or the other way).

Comment: @user3528438 I also plan to do the same when I would start doing actual computation inside my code i.e. I will write another C-function, do some calculation there and return the result to LHS. However, right now, I just want to check if I get the conversion right. I am concerned about this line:     /* Set the output pointer to the output matrix. */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols, mxREAL); as pLHS[0] is no longer array. Should I remove this line?

Comment: I saw in Page 12 TAUCS is a C struct. The first thing you should know about mex is that the only common data structures shared by matlab and C array and scalar. Although there are ways to convert between matlab struct and C struct, I don't think they are easy to use. If you are trying to assemble a C struct in mex and pass it to matlab, you are already on the wrong track.

Comment: @user3528438 Thanks for pointed out the mistake. Though I am doing that in this example; but, luckily I am not planning to do that in original code. What I plan to do: 1) Convert Matlab sparse to TAUCS 2) Do some calculation in C 3) Return a column vector. I am concerned about the conversion part. Would you please have a look at this [C-code](http://matrixprogramming.com/files/code/benchmark/run_taucs.cpp) that I got online and confirm if I am converting right?  `Please refer to part of code marked by comment` // 2b) converting SparseMatrix to the TAUCS CCS